# Enumerate Database on SQL Server 2008 Cluster

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, database-connection, cluster-computing

Our IT department recently moved from our databases to a cluster. This move broke many legacy applications that enumerate the databases with the following code:

```
Dim objConn As ServerConnection
objConn = New ServerConnection()

If Me.ComboServers.Text.Trim.Length() > 0 Then
    objConn.ServerInstance = Me.ComboServers.Text.Trim()
End If


Me.SMOServer = New Server(objConn)
Me.ComboDatabases.Items.Clear()
For Each objDB As Database In Me.SMOServer.Databases
    Me.ComboDatabases.Items.Add(objDB.Name)
Next
```

This code works well enough when connecting to a standalone database but will not connect to a named instance on a SQL cluster.

How can I enumerate the databases on a named instance on a SQL cluster?

Comment: please no comments on the code. I did not write it, today was the first day I saw it.

Comment: Is it giving an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Are you using the instance name for the cluster or are you trying to use the instance name for one of the physical boxes?

Comment: When the server\instance is passed in for the value objConn.ServerInstance there is a connection timeout. However; I can connect fine in SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovery of named instances relies on SQL Server Browser Service. There is a known issue with the SQL Browser service and Windows Firewall that occurs on clusters. See [Unable to connect to a SQL Server named instance on a cluster](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/27/unable-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-named-instance-on-a-cluster.aspx). There are specific updates to OS and SQL itself required to be applied, see the linked article for details. A good workaround is to use static ports and explicitly specify the listening port in the connection string(s).